# Error: "Couldn't decode uint256 from ABI: 0x" Private Ethereum Network web3js MetaMask

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, metamask

I am trying to call the smart contract for data using this code and every time I am getting this error. I am using a Private Ethereum Network with MetaMask. The calling function is given below.

```
function certify_find (hash, callback) {
  contract.methods.findDocHash(hash).call( function (error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    callback(error, null);
  }else {
    let resultObj = {
      mineTime:  new Date(result[0] * 1000),
      blockNumber: result[1],
      instituteName: result[2],
      recipientName: result[3],
      courseName: result[4],
      marks: result[5],
      dateOfCompletion: result[6]
   }
   callback(null, resultObj);
  }
 }); 
};
```

The ABI is given below

```
[
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bytes32",
            "name": "hash",
            "type": "bytes32"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "insti",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "reci",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "course",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "grade",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "doc",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "name": "addDocHash",
    "outputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "inputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "constructor"
},
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bytes32",
            "name": "hash",
            "type": "bytes32"
        }
    ],
    "name": "findDocHash",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
}
]
```

This is the smart contract

```
pragma solidity >= 0.5.0 < 0.7.0;

contract Certify {

struct Record {
    uint mineTime;
    uint blockNumber;
    string instituteName;
    string recipientName;
    string courseName;
    string marks;
    string dateOfCompletion;
}

mapping (bytes32 => Record) private docHashes;

constructor() public {

}

// function that is used to store records on the blockchain
function addDocHash(bytes32 hash, string memory insti, string memory reci, string memory course, string memory grade, string memory doc ) public {
    Record memory newRecord = Record(now, block.number,insti,reci,course,grade,doc);
    docHashes[hash] = newRecord;
}

// verify weather a hash exists on the blockchain and retrieve the corresponding record
function findDocHash(bytes32 hash) public view returns(uint, uint, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory) {
    return (docHashes[hash].mineTime, docHashes[hash].blockNumber, docHashes[hash].instituteName, 
                docHashes[hash].recipientName, docHashes[hash].courseName, docHashes[hash].marks, docHashes[hash].dateOfCompletion);
}
}
```

Comment: You should by the least indicate exactly which line in your code throws this error!

Comment: contract.methods.findDocHash(hash).call( function (error, result) outputs error = "Error: Couldn't decode uint256 from ABI: 0x and result = null

Comment: What is the value of `hash`?

Comment: 0xf236f925722dd04d30ccb29fa44711028f8f6ede2731d1575dc2fc8e7aadbcf8

Comment: What is the value of `typeof hash`?

Comment: typeof(hash) outputs string

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: I updated web3 to 1.2.9 and now in error variable I am getting this "Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced."  Please help me!

Comment: How do you initialize `contract`?

Comment: contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,address)

Comment: The contract deployed at `address` is probably different from the contract shown in your question.

Comment: I am getting this error during .call() only. Data is being published without any error during contract.methods.addDocHash(hash, **String name**).send() function. If what you're saying is correct then I should get error during publishing also right?

Comment: No, wrong. The contract deployed at `address` maybe identical to the contract shown in your question with its `addDocHash` function, but different from the contract shown in your question with its `findDocHash` function (which means that the two contracts are not identical).

Comment: but I have only 1 account and only one contract deployed in that address using remix injected web3